# In Resource Tab in Chrome under Frames, scripts are duplicated, Is this an issue

Tags: google-chrome, testing, web

I was testing a site which uses service worker,
I noticed that when clicked on the logo in the site, in Resource Tab in Chrome under Frames, scripts were getting duplicated. While it doesn't create any problems to the functionality, but i want to know whether this an issue?

[image: Duplicate scripts]

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the issue, you should ask developer a reason for this.

If this keeps happening this will unnecessarily eat memory of end user, and will affect the performance.